# Order by nearest - PostGIS, GeoRuby, spatial_adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gis, postgis

I'm trying to do an order query that finds records nearest to the current_user.

I know the distance between the two points is: `current_location.euclidean_distance(@record.position)`

How can I work this into a PostGIS (or active_record/spatial_adapter) query?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get the 5 closest:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
ORDER BY ST_Distance(your_table.geom, ST_Geomfromtext(your point as wkt)) 
limit 5;
```

If you have a big dataset and know that you don't want to search further than , say 1 km, the query will be more efficient if you do:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE ST_DWithin(your_table.geom, ST_Geomfromtext(your point as wkt, 1000)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(your_table.geom, ST_Geomfromtext(your point as wkt))  
limit 5;
```

/Nicklas

Comment: I have my position in a helper method current_location. Do you know if it's possible to insert this into the query (rails)? Something like: `.order('ST_Distance(items.position, #{current_location})')`

Comment: Problem was I needed double quoates. `.order("#current_location")`

Comment: There is a bracket missing on the WHERE line after 'your point as wkt'

Comment: Why pass it in as wkt?

Comment: For other newbies like me, it might be helpful to know that `items` in the call to `ST_Distance` refers to the name of the DB table that has the geo-coded elements.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case somebody stumbles upon this issue in rails 4.
I am using rgeo gem and this works for me

```
scope :closest, ->(point) { order("ST_Distance(lonlat, ST_GeomFromText('#    {point.as_text}', #{SRID}))").limit(5) }
```

Comment: you should add to the answer how you define the `lonlat` in Rails / rgeo

Comment: For other newbies like me, it might be helpful to know that the value of `SRID` should be an integer that points to the universally-known ID of the coordinate system you are using to compute distances. You are _most probably_ looking to use the [Geodesic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84) of the planet Earth which is ID **4326**.

Answer (score 2):

To wrap this up, with everyone's help I've got it working how I wanted:

```
order("ST_Distance(items.position, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (#{current_location.y} #{current_location.x})', #{SRID}))")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to find literally the 5 records nearest to the current_user, consider neighborhood search, which is supported by KNN index in PostGIS 2.0 (see '<->' operator):

`SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_table.geom <-> ST_Geomfromtext(your point as wkt, 1000) LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the ST_Distance documentation in PostGIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont NEED to use PostGIS, geo-kit does this perfectly using google or yahoo (I've only used Google) and in your queries you can sort by distance, its awesome..

Comment: you are right but you are restricted by google's request limit for their API. in this case it is 2500 request / 24 hrs