# Order by Nearest using PostGIS, RGeo, Spatial Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgis, rgeo

I'm asking this question because the answers I've found in [Order by nearest - PostGIS, GeoRuby, spatial_adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111627/order-by-nearest-postgis-georuby-spatial-adapter) wasn't able to provide a solution. I'm trying to create a controller method that can return the *n* closest records to a certain record's lonlat. The record it is querying against is from the same table. This concept isn't such a big stretch if I was doing this completely in SQL. That much is clear in the linked example and below is a specific case where I obtained a result:

```
condos_development=#
  SELECT id, name FROM condos
  ORDER BY ST_Distance(condos.lonlat, ST_PointFromText('POINT(-71.06 42.45)'))
condos_development-#
  LIMIT 5;
```

My problem is in making this work with ActiveRecord. I'm using a method that was inspired by the response by @dc10 but I'm unable to create a working query either through the RGeo methods, or direct SQL. Here's what I have so far:

```
def find_closest_condos(num, unit)
  result = Condo.order('ST_Distance(condos.lonlat, ST_PointFromText("#{unit.lonlat.as_text)}")')
                .limit(5)
end
```

The response from this attempt is as follows:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error
>   at or near "LIMIT" 10:29:50 rails.1  LINE 1: ...lonlat,
>   ST_PointFromText("#{unit.lonlat.as_text)}") LIMIT $1

Would someone be able to set me on the right track on how to put this work query together so that I can make it work in Rails?

Comment: Seems like the solution is to change `"#{unit.lonlat.as_text)}"`to `"#{unit.lonlat.as_text}"`

Comment: Yes.. That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with how active record is resolving your query to SQL, also the position of the Limit clause. If you change the query to this:

```
Condo.order("ST_Distance(lonlat, ST_GeomFromText('#{unit.lonlat.as_text}', 4326))")
     .limit(num)
```

You should find this works.